# Fusion.js error after running yarn dev

Tags: javascript

OS: Windows 10. I know it's bad :(

USERNAME - I just replaced my user name

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\project\fusion>node -v
v10.9.0

C:\Users\USERNAME\project\fusion>yarn -v
1.9.4
```

I ran this first:

```
yarn create fusion-app fusion
```

Then without any changes this:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\project\fusion>yarn dev
yarn run v1.9.4
warning package.json: No license field
$ fusion dev
Build completed in 4.801s

Build completed in 5.115s

Error: Cannot find module 'C:UsersUSERNAMEprojectusion
ode_modulessource-map-supportsource-map-support.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USERNAME\project\fusion\.fusion\dist\development\server\server-main.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

This obviously doesn't look good:

Error: Cannot find module **'C:UsersUSERNAMEprojectusion**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using Fusion.js and sorry about the problems you're experiencing. We're working on our long-term Windows support plan, but for now folks have had luck using Docker on Windows, which provides a reproducible environment for both development and production. We have an example boilerplate application using Docker here: https://github.com/KevinGrandon/fusion-boilerplate/tree/master/docker-fusion-app